# Postgis ST_ColorMap with mode "NEAREST" does not return a raster

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-raster

I have a color map as shown here:

```
 color_map := '0 0 0 0 0
    1 0 0 0 0
    10 128 0 230 255
    11 56 0 100 255
    12 0 0 0 255';

return ST_AsPNG(ST_ColorMap(raster_input, 1, color_map, 'EXACT'));
```

This works with the mode of 'EXACT' and returns the expected image. Now I might have additional values such as 13, 14 etc. in my raster. That is why I tried using `NEAREST` as mode for `ST_ColorMap`. Unfortunately that resulted in the PNG being always empty. So even the exactly matching values from before do no longer work.

Am I misunderstanding how the `NEAREST` mode is supposed to work, or is there an issue with my color map?